# Spring Security does not reject requests when missing HTTP basic authentication header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to setup a simple HTTP basic authentication mechanism for accessing REST endpoints in an application.

Basically, all endpoints starting with `/api/internal` shall be secured with HTTP basic authentication, while further configurations shall secure other paths with e.g. OAuth2.

The problem is that, for example, a GET request to `/api/internal/test` is allowed even when the client does not provide any credentials in the request header.

This is my current security configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class InternalApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
            auth
                    .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                    .withUser("user")
                    .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                    .roles("USER");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
            httpSecurity
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .mvcMatcher("/api/internal/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    // Other security configuration follow here...
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a complete security configuration (including other filter chaini) so that I can take a look ?

Comment: Actually, the other securiy configurations have been commented out, so this is the only active configuration. However, I found out that it works if I add `.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`.

Comment: Okay. Assuming cookie based authentication is used, if your other chain issues a cookie on path '/' so that it is applicable to both the chains. Session created because of the first chain would be applicable here. Since an authentication is present, I think Spring Security will allow request to go ahead.

Comment: When you configure `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`, your NullSessionRepository implementation is unable to retrieve any previous sessions. Hence, this time request fails because Security was not able to pull any authentication information related to cookie it just received.

Answer (score 1):

After having spent some more time on this problem, I found that the authentication works when adding the following to the chain:

`sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`